# Parsing a reddit json link to find a specific image link

Tags: json, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I don't exactly know what I'm doing here and am trying to hack together something, so far it's not working. Please feel free to criticize me. Here's my code so far:

```
import requests
import json
url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/earthporn/hot.json?limit=1'
r = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(r.text)
target = '"stickied": false, "url": "'
for target in data:
    print('Found it')
```

I'm trying to download the top picture from the earthporn subreddit each day. When I go to the above link, the actual link to the image takes place right after the "target" string. The target string should occur only once in the data, but 'Found it' is printing out twice. The idea I have in mind is to grab the link of the image which occurs right after the target, and before the next ' " ' symbol.

Comment: Try this [tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/12/scraping-images-with-python-and-scrapy/)

Comment: Did you mean `if target in data:`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 My thought was that it would print 'Found it' each time it found the target in the data, which should be just once.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood from your post, you can simply extract the url directly from `data` dict...

`url = data['data']['children'][0]['data']['url']`

hope this helps!